# Latin Modern looks different in pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, latin-modern

I realized that Latin Modern font looks heavier in XeLaTeX and lighter in pdfLaTeX. Why? How can I get the same lighter look in XeLaTeX? IMHO, the XeLaTeX look is too heavy and I'd like to have the pdfLaTeX look with XeLaTeX. (I need to use XeLaTeX due to another `.ttf` monospaced font.)

(In the screenshot below, left is pdfLaTeX and right is XeLaTeX.)

[image: Screenshot to illustrate the issue]

Comment: This is very much reader dependent. pdflatex and xelatex use different font types (type1 postscript for pdflatex, and otf for xelatex). The readers may handle these differently and therefore may look different on screen.

Comment: @ArTourter It seems you're right: I've tested with the Google Chrome's internal pdf viewer, and now there's no visual difference. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\begin{document}

\huge Desarrollo web en entorno servidor

\end{document}
```

I compiled this with

```
pdflatex -jobname desapdf desarrollo
```

and with

```
xelatex -jobname desaxe desarrollo
```

Top `pdflatex`, bottom `xelatex`:

[image]

I see no difference.

Comment: Could you please provide the full source code which produces your output? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again :). It seems to be a reader's issue, as @ArTourter suggested.

Comment: as a last favour, could you please provide both `.pdf` files, so I can test them with my viewers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RicardoPérezLópez The site doesn't allow adding PDF files.

Comment: oops, didn't know that, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As @ArTourter suggested, it seems to be a reader issue: I've tested with the Google Chrome's internal pdf viewer, and now there's no visual difference.

[image: Screenshot]

(LaTeX on left, XeLaTeX on right).

Interestingly, both Evince (the Gnome PDF viewer) and the TexStudio interval viewer has the same issue.

This is TexStudio with LaTeX output:

[image: TexStudio with LaTeX]

And this is with XeLaTeX output:

[image: TexStudio with XeLaTeX]

Maybe both Evince and TexStudio use the same render engine?

[Edit to comment that the Xpdf PDF viewer has the same issue:]

[image]